# What is wrong in calculating probability in this way?

Tags: probability, self-study

#### Problem:

Given the following information:

There are 3 urns $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

Urn $X$ contains 4 red balls and 3 black balls.

Urn $Y$ contains 5 red and 4 black balls.

Urn $Z$ contains 4 red balls and 4 black balls.

One ball is drawn from each of these urns.

What is the probability that the 3 balls drawn consist of 2 red balls and 1 black ball ?

#### My Approach:

Lets represent red balls as $1$ and black balls as $0$. Then there could be three possible ways by which the solution is possible.

$$XYZ \\
0 \ 1 \ 1 \\
1\ 0\ 1 \\
1\ 1\ 0$$

So, the result would be the sum of probabilities of these three possible ways.

In the first case, the probability of getting red ball from $X$ is $\frac{4}{7}$ then the probability of getting black ball from $Y$ is $\frac{4}{9}$ and then the probability of getting black ball from $Z$ is $\frac{4}{8} = \frac{1}{2}$. So, the probability of the first case is $\frac{4}{7} \times \frac{4}{9} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{16}{126}$

For the second case, the probability is: $\frac{3}{7} \times \frac{5}{9} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{15}{126}$

And in the third case, it is: $\frac{3}{7} \times \frac{4}{9} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{12}{126}$

So, Total probability, $P = \frac{16}{126} + \frac{15}{126} + \frac{12}{126} = \frac{43}{126}$

Where did I approached wrongly?

#### Note:

The problem I get from [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/basic-probability-puzzles-3) which is a problem solving site and it is saying that my answer is wrong.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: One useful problem-solving technique is to *write your formulas in a way that reveals the underlying pattern.* In this case your three possible ways answer the question "which urn did the black ball come from"? It could be one of 3 balls in urn $X$, whence the two red balls are (a) one of the 5 from urn $Y$ plus (b) one of the 4 from urn $Z$. The other two cases are similar. The total possibilities therefore are $$3(5)(4)+(4)4(4)+(4)(5)4.$$ The total possible combinations are $$(4+3)(5+4)(4+4).$$ *Do the calculation only at the end,* dividing the first by the second to get $204/504=17/42$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple error.  Once you started calculating probabilities for each of the three cases you switched to (1=black) and (0=red).

**edit**

Clarification for Neil G.  That was his only error.  My answer is 51/126 = 17/42.  Stupidly the site asked for a reduced fraction but said the right answer was 51/126.  This question is about the event that the sum of three independent Bernoulli samples (from different distributions) equals 2.  This occurs in three mutually exclusive cases, hence the addition, and independence justifies the multiplication.

What was the error that you are seeing in our logic?

Comment: that's not the mistake.  what's your answer?

Comment: @NeilG edited answer in response

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try the same approach assuming all of the balls are black and the draw is three black balls.

---

Whatever you do in my example problem should be the same thing as you do in your problem. For my problem you multiplied the probabilities and in yours you added them. Why does either of these things make any sense?

Comment: It is 1 obviously. All balls are black, so, one possible solution(111). (7/7)*(9/9)*(8/8)=1. I have got the solution using a different approach, but do you think that there is a problem with this approach?

Comment: @manetsus That's not what you did in your solution above.  Do exactly what you did.

Comment: Sorry, I could not get you. I rechecked it several times. but where I did not do it?

Comment: @manetsus: "So, the total probability is…"

Comment: In the total probability should not I add them all?

Comment: @manetsus Try it on the example of all black.

Comment: Sure, There is only one possible way, So, what should I add in the example of all black?

Comment: @manetsus: Whatever you do in my example problem should be the same thing as you do in your problem.  For my problem you multiplied the probabilities and in yours you added them.  Why does either of these things make any sense?

Comment: Most probably you misunderstood me. My approach is at first I have to find out how many possible ways to come with the solution(in my problem it is 3 and in your problem, it is 1). Then calculate the probability of each possible way individually and then add them up. As in my case, there are 3 possible ways, there is a matter of summing up. But in your case, there is only 1 possible way to come up with the solution. So, there is no matter of summing up one element. Sum of one element is equal to that element. So, where is the problem?

Comment: @manetsus: No.  In my case, there are still three different urns, and these can be drawn in any order.  So my problem should have the same solution as yours.

Comment: In your case, the question would be "What is the probability that the 3 balls drawn consist of 3 black balls?", right? So, why should I consider order here? only one case can be concluded to the accepted solution.

Comment: And that is in first urn I have to get black, in second urn I have to get black, and in third one, I have to get black too. So, BBB is the only possible way.

Comment: @manetsus: You should consider order so that the two problems look the same and you can figure out what you're doing wrong in the more complicated problem.

Comment: If I consider order, this approach would be more complicated as In my problem their would come 6 cases from each of the existing possible way.

Comment: Neil G.  I think this line of questioning is not quite applicable to the problem and that the original method was completely fine.  There was just a small error